# JavaFX Running a thread multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, executorservice

I am creating a food ordering system that when a button is pressed it will call a method that will then query a database to find out the current quantity, will then query another table to find out the quantity required for each dish, and will then update the database with the new quantity. This takes a second or two so I wanted to run this on a new thread everytime the user orders an item so it doesn't hang after every button press. I have attempted this using an executorService but I still get an InvocationTargetException error.

Here is the code:

```
    public ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Task<Boolean> buyDish = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
       return Datasource.getInstance().insertDishSale(dishId, cost);
    }
};

public void orderFood(ActionEvent event){
    if (event.getSource() == salmon) {
        dishId = 1;
        cost = 4.99;
        executorService.execute(buyDish);
   }
}
```

My questions are;

1. How would I be able to run this method and not cause the application to hang while the database updates are completed?
2. Is it a good idea to do this on a different thread, as I was just thinking that if another thread attempted to update the database it would be working with data that isn't up to date until all other threads have updated the database too.

EDIT-

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.lukedavies.controller.TestController$1@31bd90 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1104326[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
at com.lukedavies.controller.TestController.orderFood(TestController.java:44)
```

Comment: The stack trace looks like you have tried to execute the task after the executor service has been shut down.

Comment: That was it, there was other irrelevent stuff in that method that I left out ( it was repetitive) and I missed the shutdown at the end of the method. When should I shut down the executor service?

Comment: Shut down the executor service when you close the application (e.g. from the `Application.stop()` method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that you are trying to execute the task after you have shut down the executor service. You should typically only shut down the executor service when you exit the application, e.g.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using FXML and a controller:

```
public class MainController {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void shutdown() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private MainController mainController ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        mainController = loader.getController();

        // ...

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mainController.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Additionally, as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

> As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused.

(As an aside, note that it's also a very bad idea to reference mutable data on different threads. Your `dishId` and `cost` appear to be instance fields that are referenced from both the FX Application Thread and the background thread.)

So you cannot use the same `Task` multiple times. Just create a new one each time:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private Task<Boolean> createBuyDishTask(int dishId, double cost) {
    return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return Datasource.getInstance().insertDishSale(dishId, cost);
        }
    };
}

public void orderFood(ActionEvent event){
    if (event.getSource() == salmon) {
        executorService.execute(createBuyDishTask(1, 4.99));
   }
}
```

Comment: Copied that exact code back in and still get the same error - Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: @JohnnyB. Post the complete stack trace (not just the error message) in your question.